# Active Directory details page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, active-directory

Recently I have been making an MVC application with a fluid, responsive design in mind.  One of the views has been to implement a fast responsive active directory details page. This is the first time I've really gone head-first into using jQuery/JavaScript with JSON results.  Usually I stick to backend coding and someone else does the front-end using Kendo/Telerik controls.  I wanted to change it up a little by using jQuery/JavaScript and HTML5 whereever I can.

The page itself works as follows:

User types into `[input:project]`, which fires the autocomplete to the server, gets the persons/groups details and builds the autocomplete based on results.  If the user then selects a person/group from results the details are loaded to the right of the page.  If it's a group then I attempt to load the data so it builds the elements on the DOM dynamically and evenly.

Everything works as expected, but I would appreciate your views/comments on my JavaScript here on what I could have done better, if anything.  I'm pretty new to jQuery/JavaScript so not sure if I'm writing the functions efficiently etc.

**Partial View**

```html
<div class="tile-area">
    <div class="grid fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span2">
                <div style="margin: 20px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0 !important; ">
                    <div class="ui-widget">
                        <input id="project">
                        <input type="hidden" id="project-id">
                        <span class="icon-search" id="icon-btn-search"></span><div id="cheight"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Body container -->
            <div class="span9 person-container scroll-vertical" id="person-container">
                <!-- Force span to fix ul issue on autocomplete -->
                <div class="container">
                    <div id="peopleList">
                        <div class="listview-outlook">
                            <header>
                                <div class="p-container">
                                    <div class="p-sub-container" id="sub-container">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </header>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bg-transparent no-overflow" id="overflow"></div>
```

**Styles**

```css
<style>
    ol, ul {
        list-style: none;
    }

    #project-label {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    #project-icon {
        float: left;
        height: 32px;
        width: 32px;
    }

    #project-description {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
        display: none;
    }

    .auto-list-content {
        padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        color: rgba(120,162,47,0.9);
        height: 55px;
        background-color: honeydew;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    .auto-data {
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        margin-left: 45px;
        min-width: 200px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .auto-complete-title {
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 2px !important;
        display: block !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        white-space: nowrap !important;
        text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    }

    .auto-complete-subtitle {
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0px !important;
        display: block !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        white-space: nowrap !important;
        text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    }

    .auto-complete-remark {
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0px !important;
        display: block !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        white-space: nowrap !important;
        text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    }
    /* !Important - overrides the inline left of 15px from jquery ui (ul) element*/
    .metro ul,
    .metro ol {
        padding-left: 0px !important;
    }

    .ui-autocomplete {
        width: 301px;
        height: 55px;
        display: block !important;
    }

        .ui-autocomplete li {
            margin: 2px 0 2px 0;
            padding: 5px 0 0 0;
            width: 250px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(120,162,47,0.9);
        }

    .tile-area {
        padding: 0px !important;
    }

    .person-container {
        padding: 5px;
        /*background-image: url('images/ICO/large/User-No-Frame-Transparent.png');*/
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        /*background-color: rgba(244,145,30,0.2);*/
        background-color: rgba(120,162,47, 0.2);
    }

    /* CSS Partial view */
    .p-container {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .p-sub-container {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        /*border: 1px solid rgba(120,162,47, 1);
        background-color: rgba(120,162,47, 1);*/
    }

    .p-sub-container {
        /*border: 1px solid green;*/
    }

    .p-floating {
        position: relative;
        top: -125px;
        left: 130px;
    }

    .p-icon {
        background-image: url('images/ICO/large/User-No-Frame-Transparent-125x135.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 125px;
        width: 125px;
    }

    .p-data {
        text-align: left;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        display: block;
    }

    .p-list-item {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    .subChild {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .subChild {
        height: 160px;
        width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
</style>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
<script>
    function setHeightOfContainer() {
        var maxHeight = 800;
        var wHeight = $(window).height();
        var pContainerHeight = 700;

        $('#person-container').css("height", pContainerHeight);
        $('#overflow').css("height", calculateRemainder(wHeight, pContainerHeight));
   };

    function calculateRemainder(windowHeight, currentHeight) {
           return (windowHeight - currentHeight - findAllNavBarElements());
    }

    function findAllNavBarElements() {
        var numItems = $('.navigation-bar').length;
        var heightTotal = 0;
        if (numItems > 0) {
            /* find height of elements */
            for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
                heightTotal += $('.navigation-bar').height();
            }
        }

        return heightTotal;
    }

    $(function () {
        var personData = null;

        setHeightOfContainer();
        findAllNavBarElements();

        $("#project").autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("SearchFilterSimple", "Person")',
                    data: { wildcard: request.term },
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Name,
                                value: item.Sid,
                                desc: item.Department,
                                icon: item.Thumbnail
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (error, txtStatus) {

                    }
                });
            },
            create: function () {
                $(this).autocomplete("search", '');
            }
        })
        .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $('<li>')
            .append('<div class="auto-list-content">'
                    + '<img id="project-icon" src=images/ICO/medium/' + item.icon + ' class="icon" style="width:32px; height:32px;">'
                    + '<div class="auto-data">'
                    + '<span class="auto-complete-subtitle">' + item.label + '</span>'
                    + '<span class="auto-complete-remark">' + item.value + '</span>'
                    + '</div></li>')
              .appendTo(ul)
             .click(function () {
                 getPersons(item.value);
             })
            ;
        };

        function getPersons(sid) {
            var e = 0;
            $(".p-sub-container").empty();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetSelectedData", "Person")',
                data: { sid: sid },
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (person) {
                    processData(person);
                },
                error: function (error, txtStatus) {

                }
            });
        }

        var nameprefix = "sub-c-";
        var firstChild = null;

        function processData(personData) {
            if (personData.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < personData.length; i++) {
                    createSubContainer(i);
                }

                var child = $(".p-sub-container").find("[id*=" + nameprefix + "]"); // checks the attribute
                if (child.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
                        var c = $(child[i]);
                        createSubContainerChildren(c, personData[i]);
                    }
                    // reset firstChild
                    firstChild = null;
                }
            }
        }

        var prev = 0;

        /* functions */
        function createSubContainerChildren(c, pd) {
            var currentPerson = pd;
            var parent = $(c).parent(); // should be the sub container.
            var containerPos = $(parent).position();
            var containerMaxHeight = $(parent).outerHeight(true);
            var containerMaxWidth = $(parent).outerWidth(true);
            //find top
            var eWidth = 450;
            var currentElementPosition = $(c).position();
            var totalWidth = currentElementPosition.left + eWidth;
            var previousChild = $(c).prevAll();

            if (previousChild.length > 0) {
                // not first child
                var currentElement = firstChild.position()
                var currentNewElementPosition = currentElement.top - ($(c).outerHeight()) - (currentElement.top);//minus itself
                var currentNewElementLeft = currentElement.left + ($(c).outerWidth());
                var gutter = 10;

                var mycurrentleftposition = currentElementPosition.left;

                if (prev >= 1) {
                    c.css({
                        'top': "0px",
                        'left': "0px", //reset left
                        'border': "1px solid #0ff",
                        'float': "left"
                    });
                    //reset prev
                    prev = 0;
                } else {
                    prev = 1;
                    c.css({
                        'top': currentNewElementPosition + "px",
                        'left': "0px",
                        'border': "1px solid #ff0faa",
                        'float': "right"
                    });
                }

            } else {
                firstChild = c;
                // set its top/left too
                firstChild.css({
                    'top': "0px",
                    'left': "0px",
                    'border': "1px solid #0f0"
                });
            }
            var call = callCard(currentPerson);
            $(c).append(call.displayName).append(call.t).append(call.s);
        }

        function callCard(currentPerson) {
            var vCard = {
                s: null,
                v: null,
                t: null,
                image: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetImageThumb", "Person")',
                        data: { sname: currentPerson.SamAccountName },
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (img) {
                            vCard.v = img.nImage;
                        },
                        error: function (error, txtStatus) {
                        }
                    });
                },
                displayName: "<div>" + currentPerson.DisplayName + "</div>",
                imageThumbnail: function () {
                    vCard.image();
                    vCard.t = "<img class='p-icon' id='pid' src='data:image/png;base64," + vCard.v + "' />"
                },
                wrapper: function () {
                    vCard.s = "<div class='p-floating'><div class='p-data'>" +
                        vCard.email + vCard.telephone + vCard.sid + vCard.accountED
                },
                email: "<span class=\"p-list-item\">" + currentPerson.Email + "</span>",
                telephone: "<span class=\"p-list-item\">" + currentPerson.VoiceTelephoneNumber + "</span>",
                sid: "<span class=\"p-list-item\">" + currentPerson.Sid + "</span>",
                accountED: "<span class=\"p-list-item\">" + currentPerson.AccountExpirationDate + "</span>"
            }
            vCard.imageThumbnail();
            vCard.wrapper();
            return vCard;
        }

        function getImg(currentPerson){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetImageThumb", "Person")',
                data: { sname: currentPerson.SamAccountName },
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (img) {
                    return img.nImage;
                },
                error: function (error, txtStatus) {
                }
            });
        }

        function createSubContainer(a) {
            $(".p-sub-container").addClass('sub').append($('<div />', {
                id: nameprefix + a
            }).addClass('subChild'));
        };

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

From a once over,

- `s`, `v` and `t` are unfortunately named properties of `vCard`
- I am confused between the code in `vCard.image` and `getImg`, they both call `'@Url.Action("GetImageThumb", "Person")'`, room for de-duping code ? It seems you never call `getImg`.
- `vCard` has data, data retrieval functions and formatting functions. That is too much for 1 object
- In `getPersons` you should have `function (persons) {` <- not `person` but `persons`
- You never use `var e` in `getPersons` ( consider using JsHint.com ! )
- You have a number of semicolon warnings in JsHint
- You should clean up the commented out css lines
- Using `!important` sometimes must be done, but it is a code smell. I like how you put `/* !Important - overrides the inline left of 15px from jquery ui (ul) element*/` you should put a similar comment for the other places where you use `!important`
- As reader, I see a lot of ( hard to follow ) code that is positioning elements. Automatically I wonder, did the author go all the way trying to solve this with css or did the author take the easy way out ? You should comment why you could not position your elements correctly without JavaScript ( or, try harder to place elements with css )

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Really appreciate them.  As this is the first attempt really at writing javascript i'm please that your once over has deemed only a few results.  Hopefully i'm heading in the right direction.